# Seeing multiple ios simulators of the same type

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

I am having an issue while running my project. I am seeing two simulators each of the same type.

Like i have two iPad 4.1, two iphone 4.1 and so on. I think this is causing an issue while testing the app on my phone.

I tried to restart xcode and kill all the processes and restarted my computer.

I tried to create a new scheme but that didn't work.

I tried to delete the project from the organizer that didn't help either.

Has anyone had this issue and managed to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about seeing 2 simulators of the same type in your Scheme dropdown?

If so maybe try the following (make sure xcode is not currently running)

1. cd into your .xcodeproj directory.
2. delete the xcuserdata directory
3. cd into project.xcworkspace
4. delete the xcuserdata directory
5. Launch xcode project

I have resolved issues sometimes when I have had multiple or old targets appearing in the dropdown in xcode.